# Why are my label different sizes even though the widths are equal?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a frame, that is in `row = 0`,  that contains the text `High` and `Low` which I would like to have in `column = 2` & `column = 3`. I have another row below it that contains a numerical value. however on the label I set the width to all be equal to 7.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
##Forecast Frame
self.ForecastFrame = Frame(self, bg='black')
self.ForecastFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

##Forecast Title
self.forecastTitle = Frame(self.ForecastFrame, bg='white')
self.forecastTitle.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = E)      

self.forecastTitleHighLabel = Label(self.forecastTitle, text='High', font=('HelveticaNeue Light', 12), fg='white', bg='green', width = '7', anchor='center')
self.forecastTitleHighLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = E)

self.forecastTitleLowLabel = Label(self.forecastTitle, text='Low', font=('HelveticaNeue Light', 12), fg='white', bg='blue', width = '7', anchor='center')
self.forecastTitleLowLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = E)

##Forecast One Labels
self.forecastOneDate = ''
self.forecastOneIcon = ''
self.forecastOneHigh = ''
self.forecastOneLow = ''

self.forecastOne = Frame(self.ForecastFrame, bg='black')
self.forecastOne.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

self.forecastOneDateLabel = Label(self.forecastOne, font=('HelveticaNeue Light', 12), fg='white', bg='yellow', width=10, anchor='w')
self.forecastOneDateLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

self.forecastOneIconLabel = Label(self.forecastOne, bg='red', width=50)
self.forecastOneIconLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

self.forecastOneHighLabel = Label(self.forecastOne, font=('HelveticaNeue Light', 12, 'bold'), fg='white', bg='blue', width = '7', anchor='center')
self.forecastOneHighLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = E)

self.forecastOneLowLabel = Label(self.forecastOne, font=('HelveticaNeue Light', 12, 'bold'), fg='white', bg='green', width = '7', anchor='center')
self.forecastOneLowLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = E)
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE)

Comment: Try setting `sticky=EW` to align the width of labels in same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

effbot.org: [Label](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)

> width=
>
> The width of the label. If the label displays text, the size is given in **text units**. If the label displays an image, the size is given in **pixels** (or **screen units**). If the size is set to 0, or omitted, it is calculated based on the label contents. (width/Width)

It means `width` depends on font size and weight.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


l1 = tk.Label(root, text='Hello', width=7, fg='white', bg='blue')

f = ('HelveticaNeue Light', 12)

l2 = tk.Label(root, text='Hello', width=7, fg='white', bg='green', font=f)

f = ('HelveticaNeue Light', 12, 'bold')

l3 = tk.Label(root, text='Hello', width=7, fg='white', bg='red', font=f)


l1.grid()
l2.grid()
l3.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]